# Issue with setting didSet

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage, didset

I am getting image from a url using SDWebImage and assigning it to an array like so...

```
let imgUrl = arrProduct?[indexPath.section].images[indexPath.row].url
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "appLogo.jpg")

cell.prdImgView.sd_setImage(with:imgUrl, 
                placeholderImage:placeholderImage,
                         options: []) { (image, error, imageCacheType, imageUrl) in
    arrayOfSelectedImages.append(image!)
}
```

Now I just don't want to add to an array like this. Instead, after adding the image to `arrayOfSelectedImages` I want to update this array value in `didSet` and empty the `arrayOfSelectedImages` array so that every time the array gets a new value, it updates that value in `didSet` and & arrayOfSelectedImages is emptied. So finally my array in didSet will have all the images I need and I can pass those images on to some other view...How can I achieve this..?

Comment: Where is your `didSet`?

Comment: No @Fogmeister, I didn't set the `didSet`. I wanted to set one actually. But in this case, not sure where and how..:(

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You want to append the image but in the `didSet` you want to empty the array but them you expect the array to still have the images in. Your question is really not at all clear.

Comment: By the way, if you have a property that is an array, adding and removing elements to the array will fire `didSet`

Comment: Ok...@JeremyP so u are saying that if I use `didSet` then while both adding & deleting it will be called & so I will end up removing the very objects I added...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is quite straight-forward to accomplish. You need a valid criteria to compare appended objects and, what's important, criteria you apply **before appending object** to an array, not after that. Using `didSet` to verify appended object and delete it if unsuitable, is **bad design**.

If your `UIImage` objects are not encapsulated within any other object or struct to uniquely id these objects and if you don't have an option whether or not particular image should be downloaded at all (which is the best and most proper practice), you can compare two `UIImage` objects by comparing underlying image data. This could previously be accomplished by obtaining PNG representation of an image and comparing that data, but now there's a good simple method.

> **Comparing Images**
>
> The isEqual(*:) method is the only reliable way to
>   determine whether two images contain the same image data. The image
>   objects you create may be different from each other, even when you
>   initialize them with the same cached image data. The only way to
>   determine their equality is to use the isEqual(*:) method, which
>   compares the actual image data. Listing 1 illustrates the correct and
>   incorrect ways to compare images.
>
> **<sub>https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage</sub>**

**Usage**

```
if !arrayOfSelectedImages.contains(where: { $0.isEqual(image) }) {
    arrayOfSelectedImages.append(image)
}
```

Comment: `isEqual` can be invoked through `==` which is what `contains(image)` would do.

Comment: This is wrong. Read documentation by the link. `==` is improper way to compare `UIImage` objects. `The isEqual(:) method is the only reliable way to determine whether two images contain the same image data`

Comment: Thanks @Hexfire..worked perfect!!..Just what I wanted..! Thanks again..:)...and have given an upvote also...:)

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but `didSet` will fire on a property that is an array if you modify the array, not just if you assign the array. Here is an example:

```
struct A 
{
    var anArray = [1, 2, 3]
    {
        didSet 
        {
            print("Hi, there!")
            anArray.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }
}

var a = A()

a.anArray.append(4)

// Prints Hi there!

print(a.anArray)

// prints [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Ok...@JeremyP. But my ultimate aim is this..I want to prevent the same items from getting added to the array again. In this case it seems the `image` is getting added again to the array...so I tried to use `didSet`. Any other means by which I can prevent this...?